# How to convert 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates in unity 3d and get the same distance length

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am working on a project in arcore unity3d, where I need to create a 2D polygon from the 3D coordinate points plotted using arcore application similar to the HelloAR application and get the length between the points.
Currently I have extracted the length between two points plotted in 3d using the following code

```
Vector3 dir = pointB.transform.position - pointA.transform.position;
float len = Mathf.Round(dir.magnitude * 1000) / 10 //in centimeters
```

Here I have fixed my Y-axis to zero.

How can I convert the 3D coordinate points obtained here to 2D coordinates points and get the same length as obtained in 3D.

**Edit**

Is there a way to get the equivalent 2d coordinate on 3d hit

I have tries the following code

```
var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);
GameObject obj = Instantiate(PrefabMarker, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
Vector3 x_axis = detectedPlane.CenterPose.rotation * Vector3.forward;
Vector3 z_axis= detectedPlane.CenterPose.rotation * Vector3.right;
float x = Vector3.Dot(obj.transform.position, x_axis);
float y = Vector3.Dot(obj.transform.position, z_axis);
```

But the length does not match

Thank you.

Comment: What coordinate system do you want the 2D points in?   The XY plane?  The ZY plane?  The plane of the polygon?

Comment: @LeoBartkus:thanks for your reply, I want the output in XY plane

Comment: @LeoBartkus: i read somewhere that a 2D graph can be obtained by eliminating the Y axis and just keeping XZ axis. This didn't work for me. Actually I need the length between the two points in 2D and 3D to be same.

Comment: Right, so what you really need to do is rotate the polygon to lay flat on the ground.   On way to do this is to pass the face normal to Quaternion.LookRotation and then take that quaternion's inverse, use that to rotate the polygon, and -then- you can eliminate the Y axis.

Comment: @LeoBartkus: is there a way to do it for a single 3D point, I mean on hit on 3D can I get the equivalent 2D coordinates